# Can not access xterm via Gnome-Terminal

Tags: linux, ssh, rhel, gnome, xterm

Our client wants to somehow call `xterm` from `gnome-terminal` and plans to do it on a remote server with a single `ssh` command.

I can access xterm when I ssh to remote server with -X and call gnome-terminal and run xterm command on gnome-terminal. Like as follows;

```
ssh -X user@serverIP
dbus-launch gnome-terminal
xterm  # in gnome-terminal
```

However, when I want to do all this in one command, I can still get `gnome-terminal` but when I run `xterm` command on gnome I get the following error

```
xterm: Xt error: Can't open display: localhost:77.0
```

The command I mentioned is as follows;

```
ssh -X user@serverIP 'LANG=en_US.UTF-8 dbus-launch gnome-terminal'
```

and my OS is

```
[user@mGF48 ~]# cat /etc/redhat-release
Red Hat Enterprise Linux release 8.4 (Ootpa)
```

I think ssh config and display settings are working ok but I do not know where the problem is.

Comment: Invoking ssh that way, there's no terminal connection (use the "-t" option in that case -- which would make this a duplicate).

Answer (score 0):

A Graphical application like `gnome-application` needs a graphical libraries.

You have to install GUI related package to run it.

```
# yum install xorg-x11-xauth
```

For more information check this [link](https://yum-info.contradodigital.com/view-package/base/xorg-x11-xauth/)

Comment: I do not think this is relevant. Xauth is already installed on both machines

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).